# Best practice to define the load order of CSS files in a RoR project?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Trying to get my RoR project to load a separate Variables and Toolset CSS file prior to the rest, I can use @import, but is there an easy way to do it using the require line in the application.css, which is best practice?

My applications.css currently looks like this;

```
*= require_self
*= require variables
*= require toolset
*= require index
```

I'm getting the error, Undefined variable: "$primary".

The Variables.scss contains the "$primary" variable and the index.scss contains the selectors & parameters that uses the variables.

Comment: The "require" line is not best-practice all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the way Rails puts together your SASS files (the ones that end `.scss`), and because of the way that SASS works, the way to make this work is to create a `my_scss.scss` file, require it in `application.css`, and then do the `@import`s in the `my_scss.scss` file (you can call that file anything you want, of course).

Comment: Thanks, I've created an extra SCSS file called tree.scss and I'm able to run it in the correct order in there.